# lower_bound on a vector of pair after checking one value of pair

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, std-pair, lower-bound

I have a vector of pairs `vector< pair< string,int> >` in `C++` and i want to lower_bound on string value but with additional constraint that the second value of pair should be less than or equal to a given value.
Currently i am doing it using a compare template

```
bool compare(const T &a,const T &b){
if (a.first<=b.first&&b.second<=a.second) return true;
}
```

but it is not working properly.
The vector is sorted according to the first value of pair.
Example->The vector has following contents:

```
abcd,1
abcde,4
abcdex,3
abce,2
```

and i want to lower_bound on `abc,3` so it should return `abcd,1` but it is returning `abcdex,3`.Please help.

Comment: then your vector is not sorted by your compare and so lower_bound by compare in it does not make sense.

Comment: please suggest a way to do the task.Please.And even after sorting it by compare the answer is wrong for some cases.And how come for this example the vector is not sorted by compare?

Comment: It sounds like you want it sorted one way and searched another. You'd need 2 comparison functions.

Comment: is `string("abcde") <= string("abcdex") && 4 <= 3`? No. So not sorted by compare.

Comment: Err, except that `string("abcdex") <= string("abcde") && 3 <= 4` is _also_ false.

Comment: Just to make it more clear I want the first pair in the sorted  vector(according to first value) whose first value is greater than equal to given string and second value is less than equal to pair's first value

Answer (score 2):

> [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) belongs to [`binary search`](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.binary.search) algorithum family, where the elements are compared using operator< for
>   the first version, and comp for the second. The elements in the range
>   **shall already be sorted according to this same criterion** (operator< or comp), or at least partitioned with respect to val.

That means, you need to sort the vector as you mentioned in the way first, in order to act `std::lower_bound` as you expect.

Once you have sorted your vector of array in the way, you mentioned using a `compare` functor/ (I made it as a lambda), you can use `std::lower_bound`.

[**SEE LIVE HERE**](https://www.ideone.com/Zo7Ceb)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   using Pair = std::pair< std::string, int> ;
   std::vector< Pair > vec =
   {
      {"abcd", 1},
      {"abcde", 4},
      {"abcdex", 3},
      {"abce", 2}
   };
   // define the compare lambda/ functor accordingly
   auto  compare = [](const Pair &lhs, const Pair &rhs)->bool
   { return (rhs.second > lhs.second) ? false: lhs.first <= rhs.first;  };

   // sorted the vector according to the custom compare
   std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare);

   auto getLower = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Pair("abc",3), compare);

   if(getLower != vec.cend()) std::cout << getLower->first << " " << getLower->second;

  return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
abcd 1
```

---

**NOTE**: In order to use `std::lower_bound`, you need to sort your vector according to the way you wanna apply lower bound first(which is the basic).

However, in your sorting pattern, `std::lower_bound` does not know the second value of the pair(`int`) weather the array is properly sorted or not. In other words, even if you sort accordingly what you mentioned beforehand, `std::lower_bound` can not give you the desired result, as you sort the `Pair`s in such a way that `Pair.first` and `Pair.second` in opposite order.

Therefore, I suggest you to use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), which will linearly search for elements and have to use the same compare funtor as the predicate. If the vector is sorted accordingly beforehand (as you mentioned), then it should give you a proper result.

```
// sort before
checkPair =  Pair("abc",3);
auto getLower = std::find_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&checkPair](const Pair &ele) -> bool
{
   if(currPair == ele ) return true;

   return (checkPair.first >= ele.first      //--> "whose value is greater than or equal to the given string
          && ele.second < checkPair.second); //--> second value is less than a number
});

(getLower != vec.cend()) ? 
         std::cout << getLower->first << " " << getLower->second:
         std::cout << "Nothing found";
```

Comment: No worries. You probably couldn't do it because OP didn't have chat privileges. Mod-created rooms grant all participating users access.